# Referencing serverless stack name after pseudo parameters plugin deprecation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm wondering what is the correct way to reference AWS Cloudformation pseudo parameters in a serverless.yml now that [pseudo parameter plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-pseudo-parameters) has been deprecated.

All pseudo parameters are not available with the dollar sign syntax (e.g. `${aws:stackName}` is not) in a similar manner as `${aws:region}` is, for example. The serverless [documentation on pseudo parameters](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#aws-cloudformation-pseudo-parameters-and-intrinsic-functions) is very short and I am not sure I fully understand it. I have tried to use `Ref: "AWS::StackName"`, but when I try to generate an output

```
   Fn::Sub:
      - "${Stack}-someOutputResourceName"
      - Stack:
        Ref: "AWS::StackName"
```

, I get an error with `[...]/Fn::Sub/1/Stack] 'null' values are not allowed in templates`.

The pseudo-plugin page claims that

> All functionalities as provided by this plugin are now supported by Serverless Framework natively

If this is true, how should I go about using pseudo-parameters?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that while the above method does not work, I am able to use the pseudo variable directly without using `Ref`:

```
  Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-someOutputResourceName"
```